# how to add field or column in dynamoDb using console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have Create Table name called Price_Onezero and PrimaryKey is Symbol
i need to add new column or field called Price and Time because my data will be add

```
String Symbol = "EURUSD";
String Price = "1.018000"
String Time = "20200604 10:17:18.278"
```

what i have to do is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "us-west-2"))
            .build();

        DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);

        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("Price_Onezero");

        String Symbol = "EURUSD";
    }
```

how to add my string price and my string time ? and how to putitem for all of that data ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL Databases are not defined by schema, the exception to the rule for DynamoDB is the Partition key (in your case Symbol) and an optional Sort Key.

By doing the PutItem request this will add your data as long as you have the "Partition Key".

Take a read of [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.html) to understand the similarities and differences between SQL and NoSQL when DynamoDB is involved.

Comment: so how to putitem for add Price and Time to my database ?any example for that?

Comment: Examples here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-items.html under "Add a New Item to a Table". You'd simply pass all 3 parameters in with no change in the console.